# how can I integrate web app with fablo API?

Tags: api, web-applications, hyperledger-fabric, fetch-api, smartcontracts

I have deployed the smart contract(go) and the fablo network , I also have my own fablo rest APIs but I need to integrate this API with my web app how can I do it?
I'm working with this repository https://github.com/fablo-io/fablo-rest

I invoked the following steps in the readme file:

```
1- Run the script ./hyperledger-citc.sh to install some necessary software 
2- Run the command sudo ./fablo recreate to start the network
3- You may open the file  fablo-config.json to view the network components. It also includes the the installation of the chaincode "asset-transfer-basic" in Golang
4- You may use the commands sudo ./fablo [down | start | stop | up | prune | reset] to interact with the network
5- We use Fablo Rest API (https://github.com/fablo-io/fablo-rest) to interact with chaincodes and execute Transactions. 

6- Create an authorization token using the below command. This token expires in few minutes, so it needs to be regenerated
```

I have learned that I can use fetch API function but it's only receives URL as a parameter but I don't have the URL of my API

Answer (score 0):

In fabric samples,Check the rest-api-typescript project which is available under asset-basic-transfer or you can search "Asset Transfer REST API Sample" with this text on Fabric sample you will get the project info.